# Regular Expression match URL starting with a path but excludes one or more subpaths

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a URL in PHP where all paths starting with a path matches but excludes a subpath. For example I want to match any paths starting with `/admin` but not match paths starting  with `/admin/auth`.

Example path to match:
`/admin/dashboard`

Example path not to match:
`/admin/auth/login`

What I've tried but doesn't work:
`#^/admin(?<!/auth)/.*$#`

Comment: Not everything _needs_ to be done using regex ... You could simply use `str_starts_with($path, '/admin/') && !str_starts_with($path, '/admin/auth/')` here.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! `#^/admin/(?!auth/).*$#`